# Will I receive emails sent while MX records are not synced with the DNS backend?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I apparently wasn't receiving any emails for a month because my email's MX records weren't synced up with Porkbun's DNS backend. I only noticed it today and fixed it via Porkbun support.

Will I receive the emails that were sent to my address throughout the past month, or are they lost forever? How long will sending servers try before giving up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default queue lifetime is configurable.
So MTA owner may set it to what he wants.
Typically 3-5 days.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4

Answer (score 0):

As gapsf points out, it varies. However, it depends where your MX records were pointing for all this time. If they were pointing at a server which wasn't expecting to be handling emails for your domain, it would have rejected all inbound emails which would have instantly caused a delivery failure and a notification to the sender. All these emails would have been lost.

If the MX records were missing, the originating mail server would have checked if the domain itself had an A record and tried that. If that failed, all emails would have been lost.

If the MX records existed but didn't point at an active mail server, the emails would have been held and delivery would have been attempted again. You're likely to have lost the majority of emails but the recent ones should hopefully turn up within 24 hours or so.